# React project import error on having nested 'node_modules' folder

Tags: reactjs, npm

Being pretty new to React, I decided to make a fullstack app but I wanted to separate the global package.json into two differents files

So I tried to clean things a bit and went from

```
  /public
    index.html
    manijest.json
  /src
    index.js
  package.json
  server.js
```

to

```
  /client
    /public
      index.html
      manijest.json
    /src
      index.js
    package.json // Client dependencies
  package.json // Shared dependencies
  server.js
```

Running `cd client && npm install`, application works.

But when I remove the `client/node_modules` folder before installing, my React app will crash, giving the following error :

`TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'exports' of object '#<Object>'`

Tried to replace `client/node_modules` with old one, removed the root `package.json` and the root `node_modules` folder so my structure would be the following :

```
  /client
    /public
      ... same files
    /src
      ... same files
    package.json // All dependencies
  server.js
```

Also tried to replace the `client/package.json` with the original one containing all dependencies as before, but same error.

What am I missing ?

TL;DR; Generating `node_modules` from root folder and then moving it to subfolder works, but not upon installing directly from subfolder.

Comment: where have you seen shared dependencies between server and client? If you are using it for SSR, then you should have one package.json folder and one node_modules folder. otherwise the modules must be separated Also if u want one shared folder with modules for several packages u have to read topics about "lerna" and "yarn" yarn is more friendly for nested dependencies then npm

Comment: The thing is that I had only one package.json and one node_modules folder, but upon separating them I get this error